# Eigenvalue decompositin equal to singular value decomposition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

Question: when is the eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix equal to its singular value decomposition?

Answer: when A is hermitic and has positive eigenvalues.

I don't really understand. If we have A=A* and $A=U\Sigma V^*$ (where * stands for hermitic conjugate) then we have U=V by the uniqueness of SVD. But is that true? In the SVD, U and V are unique up to a constant with modules 1, right? So why is this true?

Suppose we have that, then $A=U\Sigma U^{-1}$. ($U^*=U^{-1}$ because it is unitair matrix).
And suppose the eigenvalue decomposition is $TDT^{-1}$, then we have T=U and D=$\Sigma$, again by uniqueness?

But why did we even need that U=V? I thought that if the eigenvalues are positive (and real?) then $TDT^{-1}$ is a valid SVD so it is the SVD by uniqueness?

And we also dont know the eigenvalues in D are in descending order, right? So thats a problem too?

Comment: An SVD is not necessarily unique and neither is the eigenvalue decomposition. Example could be the unity matrix. We can select vectors any direction as eigenvectors and eigenvalues will be 1. This will coincide with when any two singular values are the same. We could permute or linearly mix them in the SVD.

Comment: The columns of $U$ and $V$ are unique up to a scalar with modulus 1.

Comment: No, not in general. Take for example $I_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. You can select any ON basis for it. The trivial choice would be the trivial basis, but any rotation or reflection will do as long as $V^*$ undoes what $U$ does.